# Error: Can't compareTo()id

Tags: java, android

I keep getting error on the `compareTo` part:

> Error:(38, 36) error: cannot find symbol method
>   compareTo(CharSequence)

```
  Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>() {
        public int compare(Song a, Song b) {
            //this part down below 
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try converting the titles to strings:

```
return a.getTitle().toString().compareTo(b.getTitle().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your `getTitle()` method to return `String` instead of `CharSequence`.

Comment: Or use `a.getTitle().toString().compareTo(b.getTitle().toString())`.